# Drupal how to change url path

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite

I have server with multiply sites, for example i have domain http://site.com/ and .htaccess file in server root:

```
RewriteRule ^site.com/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) site.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And i have installed drupal in path: **C:/Servers/Web/www/site.com/drupal**
The problem was that the site links looks - `http://site.com/site.com/drupal/user/logout`, but i found the **$base_url** in `settings.php`, change it and site links looks nice `http://site.com/user/logout`. But i create new problem - all links redirect me to *index.php* (not working normaly)

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont Change $base_url>you should not touch that.I think u need a virtual host entry in webserver (for apache httpd.conf)upto  C:/Servers/Web/www/site.com